# How to compare engagement time of users based on Firebase remote config values?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-remote-config

I am setting various remote config values using Firebase for an Android app. The metrics (KPI) I care about most is average engagement time and engagement time per session. How can I view Firebase analytics with a comparison that is based on what Remote Config values where set for a user?

To be clear. I need to know, If I enable feature "A" do users use the app for more or less time.

I have also looked at A/B testing and can find no metric that is based on engagement time.

A backup question. Is app engagement time not important to other developers? If so why? Maybe I should be looking at something else as a proxy?

In addition I have linked Firebase to GA4. A solution involving Google Analytics would work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to achieve the same - evaluate A/B based on engagement time. It's possible to set `screen_view` as a metric/goal which can be kind of proxy to user engagement in some apps, but I'm not sure is Firebase just evaluate the goal metric binary (user had at least 1 event vs 0) or works with average count of events per user - this would be definitely great to understand.

But to answer your question - it's possible to evaluate the A/B or remote config value vs engagement time using an ad-hoc query in Big Query if you have your Firebase project linked to BigQuery by counting the engagement time from `user_engaged` events vs remote config value or A/B test indication see https://firebase.google.com/docs/ab-testing/abtest-config#bigquery_data_export .